# How to stop error in Visual Studio 2015 Discover test with a disposed object

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How to stop error in Visual Studio 2015 Discover test with a disposed object

I've got a simple console app that has a service reference to a SOAP web service, and I'm getting a report in my Tests window when I compile ...

```
------ Discover test started ------
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel'.
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.036) ==========
```